# I need to verify: $\overline{A\cup \overline{B}}\cup\overline{A}=\overline{A}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need to prove the following equality:

$$\overline{A\cup \overline{B}}\cup\overline{A}=\overline{A}$$

where $\overline A$ denotes the complement of $A$.

I tried to solve it by using De Morgan's Law .. the first part will be: $$(\overline A \cap B)\cup \overline A$$ and then?

Comment: Expand $\overline{A\cup\bar B}$ using De Morgan's law, just as you said, then distribute the $\cup \bar A$ over the resulting intersection.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: If you ask another question here, you can visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for short instructions about how to type math formulas on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a fine start. Then you can distribute $\overline A$ over the intersection: $$\begin{align} \overline{A\cup \overline{B}}\cup\overline{A} & = (\overline A \cap B)\cup \overline A \\&= (\overline A \cup \overline A)\cap (\overline A \cup B) \\ & = \overline A \cap (\overline A \cup B)\\ &= \overline A\end{align}$$

Comment: A¯¯¯∩(A¯¯¯∪B) = (A¯¯¯∩A)∪(A¯¯¯∩B) = A¯¯¯ ∪ O ., O means empty but I couldn't write it by my Keyboard ..

Comment: is this true ? this is for line 3